# symfony messenger No handler for message

Tags: symfony, symfony-messenger

I want to be able to handle api calls synchronoulsy and asynchronously easily.

So I created an empty interface with according handler and base class

```
interface ApiPayloadInterface
{
}

class ApiPayload implements ApiPayloadInterface
{
    /** @var array */
    public $payload;

    /** @var string */
    public $username;
}
class ApiPayloadMessageHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ApiPayloadInterface $row)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Ok, then I have empty child classes to distinguish async from sync

```
class ApiPayloadSync extends ApiPayload implements ApiPayloadInterface
{}
class ApiPayloadASync extends ApiPayload implements ApiPayloadInterface
{}
```

The selection happens in `messenger.yaml`

```
    transports:
        async: 'doctrine://default?auto_setup=false'
        sync: 
            dsn: 'sync://'
                retry_strategy:
                    max_retries: 0

        routing:
            'App\Entity\Messages\ApiPayloadSync': sync
            'App\Entity\Messages\ApiPayloadASync': async
```

Ok, this does work, but I get errors when dispatching sync payloads:

```
$this->dispatch($bSync ? new ApiPayloadSync() : new ApiPayloadASync());
```

in my log file I see dozens of such messages:

> [2019-10-27 22:11:14] messenger.CRITICAL: Error thrown while handling message App\Entity\Messages\ApiPayloadSync. Removing from transport after 3 retries. Error: "No handler for message "App\Entity\Messages\ApiPayloadSync"." {"message":"[object] (App\Entity\Messages\ApiPayloadSync: {"payload":{"action":"mdcadd",...})","class":"App\Entity\Messages\ApiPayloadSync","retryCount":3,"error":"No handler for message "App\Entity\Messages\ApiPayloadSync".","exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Messenger\Exception\NoHandlerForMessageException(code: 0): No handler for message "App\Entity\Messages\ApiPayloadSync". at /var/www/xxx/vendor/symfony/messenger/Middleware/HandleMessageMiddleware.php:75)"} []

So, the framework does start retries although I configured it to not perform any (for the sync transport)

Comment: I think you can't use an Interface like that, did you check https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/27188 and https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27076?

Comment: You should typehint by class not interface...

Comment: or configure manually your messenger handler https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#manually-configuring-handlers

Comment: Hmm, these (relatively old) issues say that interfaces can't be used but it seems to be recognised: `# bin/console debug:messenger
...
The following messages can be dispatched:

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  App\Entity\Messages\ApiPayloadInterface                                     
      handled by App\MessageHandler\ApiPayloadMessageHandler  `

Comment: hmm...
```
A message handler is a PHP callable, the recommended way to create it is to create a class that implements MessageHandlerInterface and has an __invoke() method that's type-hinted with the message class (or a message interface):
``` taken from https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#creating-a-message-handler

Comment: Works as expected in 5.1.